# Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of runtime.sendMessage: Could not serialize message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a chrome extension which reminds people to take 5 minute breaks every hour, but when I run it the browser crashes and an error comes - the timer doesn't work:-

`Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of runtime.sendMessage(optional string extensionId, any message, optional object options, optional function responseCallback): Could not serialize message.`

Here's my background.js

```
var time;
var breakTime = 60000 * 1; //in milliseconds
const opt_breakStart = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "Breaktime!!!",
  message: "You've worked a lot, time to take a little 5 minute break! :)",
  iconUrl: "icons/icon128.png",
};
const opt_breakOver = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "Breakover!!!",
  message: "Break over :( But see you again in an hour :)",
  iconUrl: "icons/icon128.png",
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  timer();
});

function timer() {
  time = 60; //in seconds
  message = { msg: "started" };
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
  id = setInterval(function () {
    if (time > 0) {
      let mins = Math.floor(time / 60);
      let sec = time % 60;
      message = { msg: mins + ":" + sec };
      //send the time of that instance in the format "min : sec" to the popup.js to show
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
      time -= 1;
    } else {
      //shows the message "BREAKTIME!!!" when it starts
      chrome.notifications.create("breakStart", opt_breakStart);
      message = { msg: "break" };
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
      setTimeout(function () {
        chrome.notifications.create("breakOver", opt_breakOver);
        clearInterval(id);
      }, breakTime);
    }
  }, 1000);
  timer();
}
```

And here's my showTime.js which shows the time into the popup:-

```
var labelTime = document.querySelector("#nbi");
var showTime = document.querySelector("#timeFromBreak"); //time left for next break
var svgContainer = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var circleSVG = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  //receives the time from background.js and shows it
  if (message.msg == "break") {
    labelTime.style.visibility = "hidden";
    showTime.textContent = "BREAKTIME!!!";
    circleSVG.style.display = "none";
  } else if (message.msg == "started") {
    labelTime.style.visibility = "visible";
    circleSVG.style.display = "initial";
    showTime.textContent = message.msg;
  } else {
    showTime.textContent = message.msg;
  }
});
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Why is `timer()` calling itself recursively?

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to run itself again and again, so that after every 1 hour, or when the setInterval is cleared, it can run again and the timer doesn't stop

Comment: But you're running it an infinite number of times, since you have no condition on the recursion.

Comment: `message` and `time` should be local variables.

Comment: sendMessage calls looks fine, the message simply cannot be non-serializable unless you modify Object.prototype somewhere else so I guess it's a bug in Chrome or you're looking at an old error in chrome://extensions page - the error list is not auto-cleared, you need to clear it manually.

Comment: The browser crash is almost certainly because of the infinite recursion, not `sendMessage()`

Comment: `id` should also be a local variable.

Comment: If you want to restart the `setInterval()` add a button that calls `timer()`.